# Wiki - Making a new page from the subsection of an other, and update automatically

Tags: mediawiki, wiki

I need to turn a subsection of a wiki page into a new page on the wiki. The og page will stay untouched.

If the subsection of the og page is edited, how can I link the two pages to have the copied page be updated automatically?

I thought about turning the original pages into a portal with boxes like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page but then I won't have the automatic content boxes, which are very important - so if you know how to still have them that would work great too!

If we can't do it on wiki, are there any other ways ? I am only decent at VBA...

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [template](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Templates) and edit/update it directly, not the pages in which it's embedded.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Labeled Section Transclusion](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Labeled_Section_Transclusion) extension.